# How to display background behind string

Tags: java, swing, graphics, background

I am developing a text RPG engine in Java. If you couldn't tell by my problem, I am a noob at this. Anyway, I want text to appear over a background, narrating a story, however, whenever I implement the string, I can only see the string over a white background, not the blue one which I originally programmed. Here's the paint methods I use  for the text and the background:

```
 public GamePanel(){

        setPreferredSize(gameDim);
        setBackground(Color.BLUE);
        setFocusable(true);
        requestFocus(true);

    }

    public void paint(Graphics g){

        paintComponent(dbg);

    }

    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {

        dbImage = createImage(getWidth(), getHeight());
        dbg = dbImage.getGraphics();
        g.drawImage(dbImage, 0, 0, this);
        g.drawString("Hello World", 250, 250);

    }
```

Here's the whole GamePanel class just in case you need it:

```
package main;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Image;

import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class GamePanel extends JPanel{

    //Double buffering
        private Image dbImage;
        private Graphics dbg;

    //JPanel variables
        static final int GWIDTH = 500, GHEIGHT = 500;
        static final Dimension gameDim = new Dimension(GWIDTH, GHEIGHT);

    //Game variables
        private Thread game;
        private volatile boolean running = false;

    public GamePanel(){

        setPreferredSize(gameDim);
        setBackground(Color.BLUE);
        setFocusable(true);
        requestFocus(true);

    }

    public void paint(Graphics g){

        dbImage = createImage(getWidth(), getHeight());
        dbg = dbImage.getGraphics();
        paintComponent(dbg);
        g.drawImage(dbImage, 0, 0, this);

    }

    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {

        g.drawString("Hello World", 250, 250);

    }


    private void log(String s){
        System.out.println(s);
    }

}
```

Thank you for your time.

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Answer (score 0):

You should not override the paint(Graphics) method. Move the code you have there -- except the `paintComponent(dbg);` line which you won't need -- to the paintComponent method and the entire problem might be solved.

Comment: public GamePanel(){
  
  setPreferredSize(gameDim);
  setBackground(Color.BLUE);
  setFocusable(true);
  requestFocus(true);
  
 }
 
 public void paint(Graphics g){
  
  paintComponent(dbg);
  
 }

 public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
  
  dbImage = createImage(getWidth(), getHeight());
  dbg = dbImage.getGraphics();
  g.drawImage(dbImage, 0, 0, this);
  g.drawString("Hello World", 250, 250);
 
 }

Comment: I think you should remove your `public void paint(Graphics g)` method completely.

Comment: That doesn't show the blue background though, it just shows the "Hello World" on a blank white screen.

Comment: @user163505 don't forget to call super.paintComponent in your override!